# not firing event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a list that page load, loads items. and when click checkbox in page  load items with json.

```
$('.content-items:checkbox').on('change',
  function () {
    $.get(newUrl, function (data) {

      $("#ProductsPartialView").empty();
      $("#ProductsPartialView").append(data);
      $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');

    }).fail(function (xhr, err) {
      alert("readyState: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status);
      alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
    });
  });
```

when click items element run a function.

```
$('.compare-items:checkbox').on('change',
   function() {
      $('#loadingModal').modal('show');
      var value = $(this).data('id');
      $.getJSON("/store/AddToCompare", {
         id: value, add: true
      }, function (result) {
         $(".compare-footer").show();
         $(".compare-count").html(result);
         $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');
      });
    }
});
```

when load items in page load, fire this jquery, but when load items with json in first code, don't fire second function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for that you need `$(document).on(event,selector, cb{});` when you want to do action on dynamic generated data

```
$(document).on('change','.compare-items:checkbox',
   function() {...
```